# android how ot update progressBar for earch item in a listview

Tags: android, listview

in my app i have a list view with multiple items each item has its own progress bar. when i click on the item the download starts but the progress bar is displayed only on the first item and when i start the second item download the again the progress bar is distpalyed on the first item! any ideas?

here is the code for downloader class:

```
public class ApkUpdater
{
    private Activity ApkUpdater;
    private String applicationApk;
    private DownloadManager manager;
    private String name;
    private String cancel;
    private String path;
    private String fileName;
    private long downloadId;
    private int size;
    private boolean downloading;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ImageView cancelBtn;
    private ImageView installBtn;


    public ApkUpdater(Activity activity){ ApkUpdater = activity; }


    public void setParameters(String path, String fileName,int size)
    {
        this.path = path;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.size = size;
         startDownload();
    }

    public void startDownload()
    {
        try
        {
            String url = IPClass.SERVERIP + path;

            System.out.println(url);

            applicationApk = URLUtil.guessFileName(url + fileName, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url + fileName + ".apk"));

            DownloadManager.Request downloadRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url + fileName + ".apk"));

            downloadRequest.setTitle("Downloading...");

            downloadRequest.setDescription("test");

            downloadRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

            downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

            downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/appsaraai/", applicationApk + ".apk");

            manager = (DownloadManager) ApkUpdater.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

            downloadId = manager.enqueue(downloadRequest);

            cancelBtn = (ImageView) ApkUpdater.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            installBtn = (ImageView) ApkUpdater.findViewById(R.id.install);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Hi", ex.toString());
        }

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                progressBar();
                int appSizeInBytes = size * 1024 *1024;
                int bytes_downloaded;
                downloading = true;
                cancel = "false";
                Cursor cursor;

                while (downloading && cancel.equals("false"))
                {
                    DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    q.setFilterById(downloadId);
                    cursor = manager.query(q);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));

                    int dl_progress = (int)((bytes_downloaded * 100L)/appSizeInBytes);

                    if(dl_progress != -1){ progressBar.setProgress(dl_progress); }

                    int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));

                    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/appsaraai/" + fileName + ".apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        ApkUpdater.startActivity(intent);

                        downloading = false;

                    }
                  cursor.close();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }


    public ProgressBar progressBar()
    {
        ApkUpdater.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                progressBar = (ProgressBar) ApkUpdater.findViewById(R.id.updateProgress);
                progressBar.setRotation(180);
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                progressBar.setMax(100);
            }

        });

                return progressBar;

    }

}
```

and this is the code for adapter class:

```
public class UpdateListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<ApplicationPojo> applicationList = null;
    private ArrayList<ApplicationPojo> arraylist;
    private String category;
    private ApkUpdater updater;
    ProgressBar updateProgress;

    public UpdateListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ApplicationPojo> applicationList)
    {
        mContext = context;
        this.updater = new ApkUpdater((Activity) mContext);
        this.applicationList = applicationList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList();
        this.arraylist.addAll(applicationList);
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView logo;
        TextView appName;
        TextView developer;
        TextView rate;
        //ProgressBar progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return applicationList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationPojo getItem(int position) {
        return applicationList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleapp, null);
            holder.logo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.appLogo);
            holder.appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.appName);
            holder.developer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.developer);
            holder.rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rateApp);
            //updateProgress = holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.updateProgress);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        try {
            String logoName = applicationList.get(position).getLogo();
            Bitmap logoImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(IPClass.SERVERIP + logoName).getContent());
            holder.logo.setImageBitmap(logoImg);
            holder.appName.setText(applicationList.get(position).getName());
            holder.developer.setText(applicationList.get(position).getDeveloper());
            holder.rate.setText(String.valueOf(applicationList.get(position).getRate()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Adapter Exception", ex.toString());
        }

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {   @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                String path = applicationList.get(position).getPath();
                String fileName = applicationList.get(position).getFileName();
                int size = applicationList.get(position).getSize();
                updater.setParameters(path,fileName,size);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a model class and use its `List` in the `UpdateListViewAdapter` .
Your model class can contain a integer field with current progress value.
You can set its value to the progress bar in your `public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)` method.
When the value of your model class changes you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `UpdateListViewAdapter` instance from your `Activity` class to refresh the view.